# Excel Byte Stream in Java File IO

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I know very little java. So Please help me in right direction.

My requirement is I have to upload an excel in HTML form and I have to have excel byte array in an object in servlet. Is this possible without third party api?

I know Apache POI API will give me the answer. But as per my requirement I cannot use any third party api.

Please Help.

Comment: Wouldnt like to contemplate doing this _without_ a 3rd party API.

Comment: If you want to do this without 3rd party libraries you could export excel files as csv to simplify the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this through Struts form bean and form file.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the development time, it is a good idea to use third party libraries.

Other option are,

- you can write a VB script to parse the Excel and call it from java.
- You can write C++ application that makes use of COM and produces required result. Then this can be exposed as native in the Java.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of impossible to parse standard excel file without any 3rd party library in Java, only if you enforce all the users must upload files of CSV format, which is very easy to handle.